# Populate a model and access it anywhere on the app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm fairly new to razor pages Asp.Net MVC Razor pages,
I created a model with the user fields and wanted to fill it with data once i logged in and access that same data in other pages by calling on the model instead of making another db call

This is my code currently

Model:

```
 public class Utilizador
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(100)]
    public string password { get; set; }

   
}
```

then i added a sigleton to Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Utilizador>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your data in the [`Session`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-and-get-session-values) or `Cache` during the first login verification, and then you can call the data directly from the Session without calling the database again.

**My test code:**

**Utilizador.cs:**

```
public class Utilizador
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }     
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddScoped<Utilizador>();
    services.AddSession();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // other middleware
    app.UseSession();
    // other middleware
}
```

**Test1.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class Test1Model : PageModel
{
    private readonly Utilizador _Utilizador;

    private Utilizador model { get; set; }

    public Utilizador getValue { get; set; }

    public Test1Model(Utilizador Utilizador)
    {
        _Utilizador=Utilizador;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
    {
        if (id == 1)
        {
            _Utilizador.username = "MyTest";
            _Utilizador.test = "Success";
        }
        else 
        {
            _Utilizador.username = "MyTest";
            _Utilizador.test = "Fail";
        }
        model = _Utilizador;

        HttpContext.Session.Set<Utilizador>(id.ToString(),model);

        getValue=HttpContext.Session.Get<Utilizador>(id.ToString());

        return Page();   
      }
}
```

Get data directly from the corresponding page:

**Test1.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model CacheTest.Pages.TestPage.Test1Model

<div>@Model.getValue.username</div>
<div>@Model.getValue.test</div>
```

**Test2.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class Test2Model : PageModel
{
    public Utilizador getValue { get; set; }
    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        getValue = HttpContext.Session.Get<Utilizador>(id.ToString());
    }        
}
```

**Test2.cshtml:**

```
@page
@model CacheTest.Pages.TestPage.Test2Model

<div>@Model.getValue.username</div>
<div>@Model.getValue.test</div>
```

#### Test Result

In Test1, store first and then read:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Directly read the data stored in the session in Test2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try with EF Core,the official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/sql?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio